# jQuery Ajax request to Web Method

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to send data to my code behind method. It works except when I add to the `data` param.

```
function (obj) {
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "Pages.aspx/EditPage",
       data: "{'nodeID': '" + $(this).attr('id') + "'}",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (msg) {
               // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
       }
     });
    }
```

Why is the param i added causing the Web Method to not get hit?

UPDATE: After seeing what client side errors were being thrown it seems that the ID is undefined. Is my method of getting the elements ID incorrect? Keep in mind I am using jsTree and ca I possibly use (obj)?

Comment: JSON uses double quotes around the properties, so `'{"nodeID" : "' + $(this).attr('id') + '"}'` may be worth a shot.

Comment: It's embedded within a jsTree that's why it looks like that. @Robert I tried switching the quotes around and it didn't work. When the data param values are removed the Web Service get's hit properly.

Comment: What do you see when you run your code and analyze the traffic using FireBug or Fiddler?  Are you getting an error back from your service?  Also, add an error handler to your `$.ajax` call to get some information about the failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging in Chrome, I discovered the ID wasn't defined. I rewrote the date param to:

```
data: '{"nodeID": "' + obj.attr('id') + '"}',
```

because the `obj` is the node i'm currently on in jsTree.

Thanks to everyone reminding me to debug in either FF or Chrome and adjusting the quotation marks.

Comment: @bryan thats great , you can acknowledge the same by giving...voting..any way your issue is resolved great

Answer (score 1):

try something as below:

```
jQuery.parseJSON('{"name":"John"}');
```

Comment: I tried `var nodeID = jQuery.parseJSON('{"nodeID": "' + $(this).attr('id') + '"}');` and setting `data: nodeID,` but no luck. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @please check in firebug net panel how the data is going to backend.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
data: "{nodeID: '" + $(this).attr('id') + "'}",
```

Edit: as for getting id, you can use `this.id`

Answer (score 0):

A few things to try

1. Remove the contentType
2. Remove the quotes around the JSON keys
3. Swap the single and double quotes

It will look like this:

```
function (obj) {
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "Pages.aspx/EditPage",
       data: '{nodeID: "' + $(this).attr('id') + '"}',
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (msg) {
               alert('success!');
       }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'this' reference you are using is referring to the jQuery 'this'. Therfore, your ID is not defined.

Assuming you are trying to get the id of 'obj' from your function argument, I would rewrite the function like this:

```
jQuery.fn.your_func_name = function(){

   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "Pages.aspx/EditPage",
       data: "{'nodeID': '" + $(this).attr('id') + "'}",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (msg) {
       // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.

  });

}//function
```

Use it like this:

```
$('#some_element').your_func_name();
```